# Why can't I bind a formview to this datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I've got this code here:

```
SqlCommand CodeStatus = new SqlCommand(SQL, DB);        
DB.Open();
Reader = CodeStatus.ExecuteReader();
FormView1.DataSource = Reader;
FormView1.DataBind();
DB.Close();
```

It works with a gridview, which then displays the data, but with this formview it doesn't display the data. Why not? The default mode is read only, which should just display the data..right?

Comment: Are you getting any error?? Do you have a template set in formview??

Comment: Try posting the code for your formview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN defines FormvView as **"A FormView displays the values of a single record from a data source using user-defined templates."**

So you will need to look at a few things-

1. 1.Test what your reader has. Does it even have rows. Trivial but a common
   problem.
2. Provide the formview with a template in itemtemplate atleast.Because a FormView will not infer the columns if you bind it programmatically.
3. Try databinding in markup for individual template items like <%# Eval("ColName") %>.

Comment: Since the gridview worked (and returned exactly one row as expected) I assumed the formview would "know" what I wanted to display as well. It's template building time, I suppose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does your FormView have an ItemTemplate?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228089.aspx) seems to imply that although it is possible, you need one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but have you tried using a DataTable?

```
using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,connection))
{
   DataTable table = new DataTable();
   adapter.Fill(table);
   FormView1.DataSource = table;
   FormView1.DataBind();   
}
```